# Specify datasource for server before start in Weblogic 10.x

Tags: java, datasource, weblogic-10.x, mbeans

Please help with next.

I use WebLogic 10.3 to deploy my application. Actually I have one server and multiple datasources (JDBC oracle connections). I want to have a possibility to specify exact datasource for my server before starting. I have been searching for a long time in direction of:

> java weblogic.Admin [Connection and User Credentials Arguments] SET 
>   {-type mbean_type|-mbean mbean_name}    -property property1
>   property1_value     [-property property2 property2_value]

... but finally could not achieve what I need, because of:

> Sets property values for Administration MBeans or Local Configuration
>   MBeans. This command cannot be used for Runtime MBeans.